# How do I display two products side by side?

Tags: magento-1.9, product, theme, home

I'm having a difficult time setting up my organization's online store. It will consist of 2 products (Silicone wristbands, and little concrete Africas). I've followed a few instructionals but they were directed towards stores with multiple products and categories.

This is a link to the original theme.
http://demo.emthemes.com/everything/index.php/?___store=beauty_eng

I would just like my two items to display side by side, as pictured in the screenshot I've attached. Can someone please explain how to do this.

[image]

Comment: May be it have back end option check once

Comment: Any reason this can't be a category with a special template ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question related to css